# Let users edit their role from the frontend

Tags: user-roles, directory

Most site ask users to choose their role at registration (for example it can be "are you an athlete/student/worker/designer" and each of these would be a user role which would appear in a different directory) but I'd like to let them choose after registration.

How can I do this ? Is their a way to let their change their role afterwards ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a widget that updates the role:

1. Widget has a drop down select input
2. Select input submits a Ajax call to backend
3. Backend Ajax call processor updades the user meta
4. Pass the User ID along with the role ID
5. Update user meta with `update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value )`